# input type buttons to get the object in left, middle and right position

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

I did have help with this question in a previous question but now I want to use svg instead of css I have the following code http://jsfiddle.net/Len1/wzNjm/3/ but the shape doesnt go to the right, middle and left when the appropriate button is pressed can someone please help me

example of what I mean

left button pressed shape goes to the left of screen

right button pressed shape goes to the right of screen

middle button pressed shape goes to the middle of screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle with [a working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/bclennox/wzNjm/4/). A few tips:

1. Move your CSS into a `<style>` element instead of writing it inline. That avoids typos like `<div style="min-height:450px"; style="min-width:600px">` (two separate style attributes and an erroneous comma).
2. Use `margin: 0 auto;` to center block-level elements.
3. Your `<rect>` element was a different width than its containing `<svg>` element, so that was making it behave strangely.

I also colored the main `<div>` red just to make it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: thanks for your time I didnt know you could do a style for the svg code outside it thanks again :)